# Java Explicit Type casting

Tags: integer, byte, typecasting-operator

```
class Test 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
      
      int i = 135;
      byte b = (byte)i;
      System.out.println(b);
    }
}
```

output: -121  my question is how compiler is doing the round off what formula it is following internally?

Comment: See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3

Comment: "A narrowing conversion of a signed integer to an integral type T simply discards all but the n lowest order bits, where n is the number of bits used to represent type T. In addition to a possible loss of information about the magnitude of the numeric value, this may cause the sign of the resulting value to differ from the sign of the input value."